# Why can't I call Assembly functions from my C source using CodeBlocks?

Tags: c, assembly, mingw, codeblocks

I'm trying to call a simple piece of assembly (as a test for something more complex later), however when I try and run the program it crashes (This program has stopped responding).

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int bar(int param);

int main()
{
    int i=8;

    i = bar(i);

    printf("Hello world! - %i\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

**bar.S**

```
.file "bar.S"
.text

.align 8
.global bar
bar:
    add %rdi,1000;
    mov %rax,%rdi;
    ret;
```

I'm concerned that it might be something to do with the way my compiler is configured (I'm more used to the hand holding of Visual Studio than dealing with a real environment).

Comment: You probably violated the calling conventions somewhere in your assembly function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl

Comment: I found it funny that you don't consider VS a "real environment"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using at&t syntax assembly but you are apparently not familiar with it. The simple solution would be to stick `.intel_syntax noprefix` into `bar.S` so you can use intel syntax.

At&t syntax uses reversed operand order and different effective address format, among other things. You got a crash because `add %rdi, 1000` means `add [1000], rdi` in intel syntax, that is add the content of `rdi` to memory location `1000` which is out of bounds. Presumably you wanted to do `add $1000, %rdi`. To return the value you need to swap the operands of the `mov %rax, %rdi` too.

Answer (score 2):

This code is incorrect:

```
add %rdi,1000;
mov %rax,%rdi;
```

Remember that in AT&T syntax the operand order is `source, destination`. Also, immediate values should be prefixed by a `$`. So the code should be:

```
add $1000,rdi
mov %rdi,%rax
```

I removed the semicolons since they're not necessary.

Also, since you seem to be compiling for Windows you should be following [Microsoft's 64-bit calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention), not the System V one. So the argument will be in `rcx`, not in `rdi`.

Answer (score 1):

start with this

```
int bar ( int param )
{
    return(param);
}
```

compile separately and link with main, and see what main is doing and passing, note main is using edi not rdi.

Now dissassemble the function above.

```
0000000000000000 <bar>:
   0:   89 f8                   mov    %edi,%eax
   2:   c3                      retq
```

edi and eax as well.  Also note that this is ATT syntax not intel, so it is backwards the destination is on the right instead of the left.

so make different flavors of our own:

```
.global bark
bark:
    mov %edi,%eax
    addl $1000,%eax
    retq

.global barf
barf:
    addl $1000,%edi
    mov %edi,%eax
    retq


.global bar
bar:
    add $1000,%edi
    mov %edi,%eax
    retq
```

assemble and link with main instead of the C version.  And

```
./main
Hello world! - 1008
```

Basically, whatever compiler you are using, get it to generate similar/simple code which will follow its convention, then mimic that.

Note, I am using gcc not necessarily the same as what you are running, but the process is the same.